# Change the default value of a string column to real uuid()

Tags: mariadb, constraint, default-value, uuid

When I use `show create table Posts` I see this column:

```
`Slug` varchar(400) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'uuid()'
```

This means that the default value is a string. I want the default string to be a real `uuid()` function.

I want it to become:

```
`Slug` varchar(400) NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid()
```

How can I do that? What query should I write for this? No matter what I do inside the phpMyAdmin or Adminer it does not become what I want.

---

I have a column that has `'uuid()'` as its default value. I want to change to so that it becomes `uuid()`. I don't want to create a new column. I don't want to drop the column and recreate it. I want to modify it.

Answer (score 3):

You have to define the datatype to be UUID (available since MariaDB 10.7.0, see [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/uuid-data-type/)). I don't know if PHPMyAdmin or Adminer support that, but you can definitely use the `mariadb` command-line client:

```
CREATE TABLE Posts (
  Slug UUID NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid()
);
```

Then insert a row with no value for the column, and it will create a UUID value for you using the `uuid` function, as we defined for the default:

```
INSERT INTO Posts() VALUES ();

SELECT * FROM Posts;
+--------------------------------------+
| Slug                                 |
+--------------------------------------+
| 11a814f3-e42a-11ed-89f9-721e764263d8 |
+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

To change an existing column, use an ALTER TABLE statement:

```
ALTER TABLE Posts
  Slug UUID NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid();
```

(Caution: You may want to test that the above statement doesn't destroy your existing data if you have important/production data in the table already.)

Comment: No, this is not what I'm looking for. I have a column that has `'uuid()'` as its default value. I want to change to so that it becomes `uuid()`. I don't want to create a new column. I don't want to drop the column and recreate it. I want to modify it.

Comment: @MohammadMiras Then simply use an ALTER TABLE statement - I've updated my answer to show this.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot do this, but you can use a trigger to perform that action, like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_Posts
  BEFORE INSERT ON Posts 
  FOR EACH ROW
  SET new.Slug = uuid();
```

See [Can I use a function for a default value in MySql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270309/can-i-use-a-function-for-a-default-value-in-mysql) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: As per some of the answers to the referenced SO question, you *can* now use a function for a default value, both in MariaDB and in MySQL.

Answer (score -1):

In Mysql 8.0, indicate that you have an "expression" by parenthesizing it:

```
Slug UUID NOT NULL DEFAULT (uuid())
```

Comment: No, this is not what I'm looking for. I have a column that has `'uuid()'` as its default value. I want to change to so that it becomes `uuid()`. I don't want to create a new column. I don't want to drop the column and recreate it. I want to modify it.

Comment: If there are already _rows_ in the table, the best approach is to drop the _column_ and recreated it.  After all, there is nothing useful now in the column.

Comment: In my case I have this error: _Error Code: 1674. Statement is unsafe because it uses a system function that may return a different value on the slave._